# Transferring data from PC to Android Mobile

Tags: java, android

I'm new to Android programming. 
I have to send continuous data from my PC(bluetooth enabled) to an Android phone using Bluetooth. 
I have written a Java code to generate some random numbers. 
how do i send it to the phone without manually transferring it. i.e i want the java code to send a particular a particular text file/ integer stream to the phone. 
Please help. Thank u!

Comment: I am sure anyone here would love to write it for you, but in the meantime: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/wireless/bluetooth.html and http://developers.sun.com/mobility/apis/articles/bluetoothcore/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Start with the Bluetooth Chat example.